# gitlab-runner using docker executor is unable to upload artifacts

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am having issues generating artifacts in my builds.

My setup is one server, with Gitlab installed, and the same server has the runners installed and configured.

Gitlab v9.5.1
Gitlab Runner v9.5.0

Given this gitlab-ci.yaml

```
image: node:6


before_script:
    - npm install

cache:
    untracked: true
    key: '$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME'
    paths:
        - node_modules/

stages:
    - test
    - build

testJob:
    stage: test
    script:
        - npm test

buildJob:
    stage: build
    when: manual
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - dist/
    script:
        - npm run build
```

And with a configured runner using the a docker executor. Everything builds as it should, except handling of the artifacts.

When executing the buildJob manually, I get the following output

```
Uploading artifacts...
dist/: found 17 matching files                     
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=174 responseStatus=404 Not Found status=404 Not Found token=KVw9XgVH
WARNING: Retrying...                               
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=174 responseStatus=404 Not Found status=404 Not Found token=KVw9XgVH
WARNING: Retrying...                               
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=174 responseStatus=404 Not Found status=404 Not Found token=KVw9XgVH
FATAL: invalid argument
```

If I however, run the same build, on a runner installed locally on my Mac, everything is working as intended, and artifacts are correctly uploaded to the server.

This tells me that this is something to do with the docker/gitlab runner setup on my server. But I am not quite sure where to start to look.

Is this a matter of setting some permissions on the docker/runner setup?

Hope anyone can help me on my way.

Comment: Can you add `curl ipinfo.io` before you build statement and check if it is able to fetch internet

Comment: I will try tomorrow, however, I know the answer. Yes there is connection to the internet. The runner is configured to use `network_mode="host"` and the setup is able to do `npm install` and to get the docker image from dockerhub.

Comment: As I expected, `curl ipinfo.io` confirms that the docker executor has access to the internet

Comment: Possible to do more verbose logging?

Comment: I have not been able to get more verbose output, so I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Try changing `npm run build` to `NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,tls,module,timers npm run build` and that should generate a lot more log